# ubuntu apt-get Unmet dependencies for libsmbios2v5 and libsmbios2

Tags: ubuntu, installation, dependencies, package, conflict

For srvadm-idrac7 package i am facing some unmet dependencies.
while installing srvadm-omcommon, following are the dependencies:
--libsmbios2
--smbios-utils
--srvadmin-omilcore

further smbios-utils have more dependencies which includes **libsmbios2v5**

while installing libsmbios2v5 it removes libsmbios2.
I am not able to resolve this conflict between libsmbios2 and libsmbios2v5.
Is there any one to help me out
Error code is:

```
root@ubuntu16043-Standard-PC-i440FX-PIIX-1996:~# apt-get -f install libsmbios2v5
```

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libsmbios2v5 : Conflicts: libsmbios2 but 2.2.13-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Answer (score 0):

Tried this one:

```
wget https://github.com/dell/libsmbios/releases/download/v2.4.2/libsmbios-c2_2.4.2-0_amd64.deb

dpkg -i libsmbios-c2_2.4.2-0_amd64.deb
```